# How can I protect a terminal command with confirmation?

Tags: bash, confirm

I have a makefile that will deploy my current django project to my live server. Is there a way to catch the terminal command "make sync_live" and request confirmation with something like

"Deploy Changes to Live? [Y,n]"

before it executes? Either in the makefile or in a bashrc file? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate, sorry I missed it.

Comment: You may also want to know about the `dialog` command. (You probably need to install it first) Then you could use: `dialog --title "Confirmation"  --yesno "You want to do that?" 6 20`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
read -p "Deploy Changes to Live? " -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    # Execute if condition passes
fi
```